# systemd --user: Can I mask all (non-essential) global services?

Tags: xorg, systemd, 20.04

I am trying to learn more about how my desktop environment is started, especially my user services. In my current session on Ubuntu 20.04 there are several dozen services active by default most started by `systemd --user` as global services. This makes it difficult to understand what is going on.

I would like to create a separate user that I can use for debugging, experimenting and start with the smallest possible set of essential services. Like a display manager, window-manager, `dbus --session`, a panel and what ever is needed to get into a graphical session.

As a start I am looking for a way to mask or otherwise disable all `systemd --user` services only for a given user and only load some that are specified by the user explicitly (e.g. in `~/.config/systemd/user`)? Is that possible?

Comment: You're going to break your system...

Comment: Possible, but in a VM there would not be much harm and I might learn something about my system.

Comment: Eh, it's kind of like buying a brand new car, and then saying... "lets take a few parts off and lets see if it'll still run".

Comment: To pick up your analogy, what I am asking for is a way to strip down the car until only the breaks the steering wheel and the gas pedal are left. Sort of like a minimal configuration that still allows me to drive the car, but without stuff like a radio or electric windows. Once I am there I want to put back each component one by one.

Answer (score 3):

After reading more about how programs in a graphical session get started I learned that there are essentially three ways how programs can get started. The following list assumes an Xorg session, it might be different for Wayland:

- Started by display manager (e.g. gdm) or xinit
- Started via `.desktop` files found at various default paths on the system (e.g. `/etc/xdg/autostart`, or `/usr/share/applications`).
- Started as user-service by `systemd --user`

So what a graphical Xorg session ends up running will depend not only on the `systemd --user` units getting started but also on what is in `/etc/xdg/autostart` and also how your X session is configured.

It is possible to mask each systemd user service via `system --user mask $SERVICE`. A list of service can be obtained via:

```
systemctl --user list-units -t service --state=running --full --all --plain --no-legend | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'
```

As @heynnema mentioned its easily to break your system like that, for example I ended up masking my `dbus.socket` and then Xorg did not start anymore, probably because some processes that was required for the session depended on D-Bus.

## Desktop Components (e.g. XDG Autostart)

Some components of the session might be managed by XDG autostart `.desktop` files. To disable an automatically started component, the respective `.desktop` desktop file has to be copied for the current user (e.g. from `/etc/xdg/autostart` or /usr/share/applications) to `~/.config/autostart` and must contain `Hidden=true`.

However, if your session uses `systemd`, then these `.desktop` files may be automatically ignored if they contain `X-GNOME-HiddenUnderSystemd=true`.

Assuming the name of the current session is in `${XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP}` the following one liner can be used to check which components are required by your sessions and see if they are managed by systemd:

```
components=$(cat /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP.session|grep RequiredComponents | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | tr ';' '\n' | awk 'NF'); for component in $components; do file=$(locate -r "/${component}.desktop$" | grep -v "/home" ); systemd=$(grep "X-GNOME-HiddenUnderSystemd" $file); echo "$file: $systemd"; done | sort -u
```

Some aspects might be specific to the GNOME desktop.

Comment: Thank you for asking and answering your own question. I was looking for this trying to understand my own system services. Thanks again!